# regarding winform and wpf app on smart phones or tablets

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Is there any future of winform and wpf app in smart phone or tablet market. will we be able to develop applications for window store on winform or wpf. Or are they a dead technology

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think they will be dead so soon. may be yes for Winforms. but still there are tons of applications that are running on Winforms and even on consoles.

you can use XAML for smart phones as well as tables. even WinRT supports XAML. also there are new libraries out there you can write programs targeting multiple platforms such as [Portable Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The new standard for building desktop applications is WPF. This is currently not deprecated and will not be for the foreseeable future. When developing for Windows phones and tablets there is an API very similar to WPF in structure/feel (using XAML).